# Why the output for "a" is -80?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, operator-precedence, side-effects

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define ABC 20
#define XYZ 10
#define XXX ABC - XYZ

void main()
{
    int     a;

    a = XXX * 10;

    printf("\n %d \n", a);

    getch();
}
```

I thought the output should be 100 but when I saw the result I found output as -80. When I put brackets as `#define XXX (ABC-XYZ)` then I get output as 100 but without brackets I get output as -80.

Comment: the title of the question doesn't give much info about what is it about. When looking at the main page, one doesn't know if he'll have a clue before reading it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The preprocessor is a dumb beast. It works on a purely textual level, without regard for what it's doing to the code semantically. Let's see what it does in this case:

```
a = XXX * 10;
```

becomes

```
a = ABC - XYZ * 10;
```

which becomes

```
a = 20 - 10 * 10;
```

which is, obviously, `-80`.

What was probably intended was

```
#define XXX (ABC - XYZ)
```

This is one reason why macros are considered evil.

Comment: Oh thanks it was so easy and i was so confused. I think my brain is not working now a days. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
a = XXX * 10;
```

will change to the following before compilation:

```
a = 20 - 10 * 10;
```

which evaluates to `-80`

Answer (score 2):

It is calculating like this ,

20-10*10

Use braces in the macro XXX.

```
#define XXX (ABC-XYZ)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Here XXX is replaced by ABC-XYZ  So it
>   is look like the follow
>
> 20 - 10 * 10
>
> So the output is -80